# how to parse json data from facebook posts in php?

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get links of posts of a page on facebook.
I am using this code but it doesn't return anything

```
$jsonobject = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/CnCArabic?fields=posts&access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAHlqSgWNZApirCn3S8Qfds7ZCYwsgYC1suJ1OOq0NqwPcET51jGp6j6zzHOwhsgydgTzebtytMfkePchDt3gKvspWKNQZDZD');

 $mydata = json_decode($jsonobject);


 foreach($mydata->data as $x)
{
  echo $x->link . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($jsonobject)` show?

Comment: and of course, `var_dump(json_last_error())` as well? **NEVER** assume that a remote resource is working. Always check for errors.

Comment: tons of text starting with : string(71462) "{"id":"417904748263676","posts":{"data":[{"id":"417904748263676_485144041539746","from":{"category":"Games\/toys","name":"Command & Conquer: Tiberium Alliances Arabic (\u0643\u0648

Comment: json_last_error() returns int(0)

Comment: Thaty's because `data` isn't a top-level object from the link shown, `posts` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JSON you posted, you should be looking for `$mydata->posts->data`, not `$mydata->data`.